# Add space below a \colorbox

Tags: spacing, colorbox

I have created a new command using colorbox as follow:

```
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

Is there a way to increase the spacing between resheading and the bullet point? 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, a newline is just too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following adds 5pt of additional vertical space:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\overfullrule5pt
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{.85}

\newsavebox\resheadingbox
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]
  {%
    \sbox\resheadingbox
      {%
        \colorbox{mygrey}
          {%
            \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
              \small
              \bfseries
              \strut#1\strut
            \end{minipage}%
          }%
      }%
    \dp\resheadingbox\dimexpr\dp\resheadingbox+5pt\relax
    \usebox\resheadingbox
  }

\begin{document}
\noindent\resheading{something}
something else
\end{document}
```

How it works:

1. we set the results of the `\colorbox` command into a box, it is not directly printed (`\sbox\resheadingbox{...}`).
2. we enlarge this box by 5pt to the bottom (`\dp\resheadingbox=\dimexpr\dp\resheadingbox+5pt\relax`, I left out the optional `=`), for this enlargement TeX pads whitespace.
3. we output the contents of the box register (`\usebox\resheadingbox`)

I also changed the width of your `minipage`, such that the `\colorbox` will be as wide as possible without sticking into the margin (a `\colorbox` adds an `\fboxsep` on both sides as padding, we use the width of a full line minus those `2\fboxsep`). Also I used `\strut` as vertical padding inside the `\colorbox` instead of your `\vphantom{...}` construct, a `\strut` has zero width and the height and depth such that it is as big as your fontsize.

[image]

Comment: It works exactly as needed! Could you explain what is happening here? For what I can understand is that you added a box to create some whitespace. I am new to LaTeX.

Comment: @subtleseeker I've added a small explanation. Anything else you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Comment: To whomever downvoted my answer: Do you want to explain why you downvoted this and what you want me to improve?

Answer (score 2):

I propose this simple code, based on the `shaded*` environment  from the `framed` package:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{Gainsboro!50! Lavender}

\newcommand{\resheading}[1]
  {%
  \setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{1pt}
  \setlength{\FrameSep}{5pt}
\begin{shaded*}
\noindent\small\bfseries\hspace*{-2pt}#1
     \end{shaded*}\noindent }%

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah… blah blah blah…
\resheading{INDUSTRIAL TRAINING AND MINOR PROJECTS}%
Some text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]